# Function to Function variables

Tags: c++

I'm still relatively new to C++ and I know this might be a rather silly question but is there any way to share a local variable value from one function to another of a different class? Or somehow point a global variable to a function variable using the dereference operator *? Simply put, I need to access local variables of one function and utilize their values in another function of a different class.

For instance:

```
void CClassX::MyFunction1(){

int x = 8;

}

void CClassY::MyFunction2()
{

x; //utilize x in some way

for(int i; i<x; i++){}

}
```

Thanks for any comments...

Comment: You could just pass said variable as an argument to the other function (that's why functions can have arguments). But perhaps if you described [what problem you are actually trying to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), we could provide some more useful help.

Comment: cheers mate...that might work only these variables I need to access contain lengthy strings and there are many..

Comment: Your last sentence suggests (a) a global variable, (b) or reference/pointer parameter, and (c) regardless of either, a potentially significant design problem. Hopefully not, and rather you just spaced and forgot about function arguments.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this it really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah I just spaced and forgot about them...thankyou guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can do this by sending the variable by reference.And send variable to that particular function in which you want to access.

```
    **void CClassX::MyFunction1()
{

  int x = 8;
  CClassY::MyFunction2(x)
}

void CClassY::MyFunction2(int &x)
{

x; //utilize x in some way

for(int i; i<x; i++) 
{}

}
```